# Where can I discuss programming interviews?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I am a developer who is currently interviewing candidates for a developer position. I am surprised at the lack of programming skills some developers have with a "robust" resume. I would like to start a discussion on the topic of programmer interviews. Is there a place on Stack Exchange where I could have this discussion?

Comment: The answer certainly would have been "not here" Phil. So I edited the question a bit. To find out what sites in the network are about, read the relevant page in the Help Center: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Other than that, the sites in the network are not meant for discussions. Perhaps you more clearly state what you would like to ask?

Comment: There's a difference between a "question" and a "discussion starter", at least in the context of SE culture.  The SE sites are intentionally not discussion forums.  There might be a group on Facebook, or some kind of feature on LinkedIn where such a discussion would be right at home.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

All of StackExchange frowns upon "discussion."  If you have a specific, actual problem that can be reasonably factually answered, then the answer will be

programmers.stackexchange.com - if the question is really about interviewing programmers, or
workplace.stackexchange.com - if your problem isn't specific to programmers, but just to interviewing, evaluating resumes/experience, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps post it on 
Workplace.SE - if the focus is made on the lack of skills of a person with a robust resume.

Probably a good idea to ask on their meta as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for job as contractor, [Freelancing](https://freelancing.stackexchange.com/) would be a good place.

If you want to be employeed, than [Workspace.SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/), as Damien mentioned.

For more general questions about working as programmer - [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Dude - you totally misread the post :)